# Как открыть ссылку в новом окне (таблицы google)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть небольшая форма со скриптом, через которую осуществляется загрузка файлов на google диск сторонними пользователями. Пользователь вводит текст в ячейку таблицы google, в следующей ячейке ссылка на скрипт(выполняет роль кнопки "Выберите файл"), при нажатии которой открывается новая вкладка с формой. Хотелось бы, осуществить открытие данной формы в новом окне определенного размера. Заранее благодарен за советы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Такая ссылка открывается в новом окне с размером в width и height указанными в параметрах.
Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос.

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/intl/ru_ALL/drive/" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'width= 300,height=300,scrollbars=1');return false;">Ссылка</a>
```